# apache ignite or any other in memory cache for postgres

Tags: postgresql, ignite, in-memory-database

Looking for caching layer sitting on top of postgres like Redis…

If we change anything in memory it should get updated to Postgres…open source out of box integration between in memory and postgres…

I believe we can do with apache ignite..can you please point me how to do it? or any other in memory solution with Postgres

What is difference between grid gain and apache ignite?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the desired behavior could be achieved with `Apache Ignite`. You need to use [CacheStore](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) for 3rd party databases. You can even [generate](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration) an `Apache Ignite` configuration that can handle the matter by parsing your existing schema through a `JDBC` connection. `GridGain` [Community Edition](https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/community-edition) is a source-available fork of `Apache Ignite` maintained by [GridGain Systems](https://www.gridgain.com/) (original author of `Apache Ignite`).